# SSL Certificate Alternatives for Server to Server Communication

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate

I am developing a Node.js app based on the Express framework.  On the backend, I need to have servers talk to each other (ie. Server 1 make a request of Server 2).

Is it OK to forego a DNS A-Record and just use the IP address of the server?

In that case, how do I authenticate the server and "client" (aka server).  I was thinking of requiring the server and "client" to each pass a secure cookie with their request and responses.  The secure cookie would then be verified before any other action was taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a IP might be more secure then DNS (e.g. no DNS spoofing), but it still allows ARP spoofing, e.g. some other computer claims to have this IP. And in case both computers are not in the same network there are also ways to hijack requests in routers etc.

The secure cookie is nothing else as a shared secret. And contrary to public key based authentication (e.g. using certificates) shared secrets have the disadvantage that you need to distribute them in a secure way so that nobody else gets access to them.

I don't think that your idea is easier to handle than SSL with certificates, so I don't see an advantage of making your own secure protocols. History tells us, that such homegrown protocols mostly provide worse security than established solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about security (these hosts are on your network, in which you have trust), don't bother with the homebaked cookies.

If you do care about security get (or generate your own) certificate and use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of requiring the server and "client" to each pass a secure cookie with their request and responses. The secure cookie would then be verified before any other action was taken.

This is not secure at all! Anybody situated on an appropriate network between the client and server can see that "secure cookie", as well as any subsequent communications. This would allow them to reuse that cookie themselves to impersonate either the client or server, and would expose any sensitive information sent in the exchange.

Use SSL. It has already solved all of these problems, and more.

Comment: To be clear, I will always use SSL.  The question involves authenticating that each server is who they say they are (ie. shared secret, SSL certificate, etc)